# Magento 2 strange issue in order collection

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, sales-order

I need order collection filter from order id.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_orderCollectionFactory; 


public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ) 
{
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getMyOrderCollection(){
   $orderIds = array();
    $i = 0;
   $orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
   foreach($orderCollection as $order){         
        if($i < 4){
            $orderIds[] = $order->getId();
        }
        $i++;
    }
   return $orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds ));
}
```

Phtml file code:

```
 <div class="block block-dashboard-orders">
    <?php $myOrders = $block->getMyOrderCollection();?>
        <div class="block-title order">
            <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Orders') ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
        <?php if (sizeof($myOrders->getItems()) > 0): ?>
            <div class="table-wrapper orders-recent">
                <table class="data table table-order-items recent" id="my-orders-table">
                    <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Recent Orders') ?></caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="col id"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order #') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col date"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Date') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col shipping"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Ship To') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col total"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Total') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col status"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Status') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Action') ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($myOrders as $order): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                                <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatDate($order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                                <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Ship To')) ?>" class="col shipping"><?php echo $order->getShippingAddress() ? $block->escapeHtml($order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
                                <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $order->formatPrice($order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                                <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $order->getStatusLabel() ?></td>
                                <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewUrl($order) ?>" class="action view">
                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('View Order') ?></span>
                                    </a>                                
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="message info empty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('You have no orders.'); ?></span></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In above code `$orderIds` is array with order id. When I fetch this function in phtml file it gives all order instead of filter collection. When I `var_dump($block->getMyOrderCollection()->getData())` it gives filtered data. What is issue? Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

I got solution as below

```
$orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $orderIds = array();
        foreach($orderCollection as $order){
                $itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
                foreach($itemCollection as $item){
                    if($item->getData('myorder_id') == 1){
                        $orderIds[] = $order->getId();                  
                    }
                }
        }
        $sellerOrders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds ));
```

In above code I have to reuse `$this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()` but why I need this second time don't know

Comment: can you add the code from your phtml file and the full code of the block?

Comment: Added block full code and phtml file code

Comment: try with `<?php foreach ($myOrders as $order): ?>` instead of `<?php foreach ($myOrders->getData() as $order): ?>`

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake i am checking another way as well so but it not working with `$myOrdes` It gives all order rather than filter collection

Comment: @Marius If i  do `var_dump($myOrdes->getData())` it gives me filtered record

Comment: try with `return $orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds ))->load();`

Comment: @QaisarSatti i have tried with it but nothing changed still same issue

Comment: @PrashantValanda i tested this code and it's working for me without any problem.

Comment: Thnaks Qaisar but it is not working for me can you please suggest something to look for?

Comment: @Marius i have updated question when i place foreach after collection then it not working.

Comment: @QaisarSatti i have updated question when i place foreach after collection then it not working.

Comment: I saw that. Sorry, but I have nothing on this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what problem but solved it by `$orderCollection->getAllIds()`

```
 public function getMyOrderCollection(){
   $orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
   $i=1;
   foreach($orderCollection->getAllIds() as $order){         
        if($i < 2){
            $orderIds[] = $order;
        }
        $i++;
    }
   return $orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds ));
    }
```

or you can try simply

```
 $orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->setPageSize(4);
```

Comment: @PrashantValanda why you are not using `setPageSize(4)`. i don't get why you are trying here?